# grails webflow notserializableexception

Tags: notserializableexception, grails-webflow, jsecurity

Grails upgrade from 1.3.7 to Grails 2.1.0.
Grails run-app executed. No errors.

Call to webflow action throws GrailsExceptionResolver error. States a grails webflow object isn’t serializable. I have navigated all classes to ensure all have ‘implements serializable’.

Error not identifying object not being serialized, so unable to identify if a class field should be made transient to be ignored by serializable runtime.

```
Full Stacktrace:
2016-12-20 09:51:25,750 [http-bio-80-exec-1] DEBUG services.RpgService  - ************ 

| Error 2016-12-20 09:51:26,450 [http-bio-80-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NotSerializableException occurred when processing request: [GET] /…/…/order
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in flow or flash scope are serializable
   Line | Method
->> 384 | doFilterInternal in org.jsecurity.web.servlet.JsecurityFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   183 | doFilter         in org.jsecurity.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter
|   886 | runTask . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run              in     ''
^   662 | run . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext
->> 1164 | writeObject0     in java.io.ObjectOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1518 | defaultWriteFields in     ''
|   1483 | writeSerialData  in     ''
|   1400 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1158 | writeObject0 . . in     ''
|   1518 | defaultWriteFields in     ''
|   1483 | writeSerialData  in     ''
|   1400 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1158 | writeObject0 . . in     ''
|   330 | writeObject      in     ''
|   1001 | writeObject . .  in java.util.HashMap
|   940 | invokeWriteObject in java.io.ObjectStreamClass
|   1469 | writeSerialData  in java.io.ObjectOutputStream
|   1400 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1158 | writeObject0 . . in     ''
|   1518 | defaultWriteFields in     ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the resolution.
My controller service was calling sessionFactory which also needed to be transient.

code change:
def sessionFactory => transient sessionFactory.
Did not need make any domain class variables transient directly.
fixed the issue.